# Масштабирование объекта Path для правильного отображение на Canvas

Tags: android

Привет всем!
Возникла следующая проблема. Необходимо нарисовать прямые и кривые линии на канве с изменённой системой координат. Пытаюсь их нарисовать, но выдаёт вот такой эффект:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Трансформацию системы координат делаю следующим образом:

```js
        canvas.save();

        float xMax = 50F;
        float xMin = 0F;
        float yMax = 50F;
        float yMin = 0F;

        float width = canvas.getWidth();
        float height = canvas.getHeight();

        float sx = width / (xMax - xMin);
        float sy = -height / (yMax - yMin);

        float trX = -xMin + 0.2F;
        float trY = -yMax;

        canvas.scale(sx, sy);
        canvas.translate(trX, trY);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(.2f);

        // Ось X
        canvas.drawLine(xMin, yMin, xMax, yMin, paint);
        canvas.drawLine(5F, yMin, 5F, yMax, paint);
        canvas.drawLine(10F, yMin, 10F, yMax, paint);

        // Ось Y
        canvas.drawLine(xMin, yMin, xMin, yMax, paint);

        canvas.drawLine(xMin, 5F, xMax, 5F, paint);
        canvas.drawLine(xMin, 10F, xMax, 10F, paint);
        canvas.drawLine(xMin, yMax, xMax, yMax, paint);

        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);

        path.moveTo(0, 0);
        path.lineTo(getWidth(), getHeight());

        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
```

Собственно вопрос. Как сделать отображение линии таким же как и осей?

Comment: Я точно не уверен но попробуйте погуглить элемент Matrix он применяется к Path, вот тут можете пример посмотреть http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/317-urok-144-risovanie-matrix-preobrazovanija.html

Comment: Пробовал его использовать, но он не работает когда система координат переопределена. Возможно что-то не так делаю...